# How to query data directly in a website instead of waiting to load for scrape?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a supermarket page, but it contains some parts with JavaScript, and I have to wait (4 seconds) because the website has to query some data and load it first to complete the HTML.
I'm using Beautifulsoup and Selenium in Python to do this task.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

waiting_time = 4 #seconds

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://www.jumbo.cl/yoghurt-loncoleche-proteina-natural-c-endulzante-140-g/p"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(waiting_time)
content = driver.page_source
soup = bs(content, 'lxml')

# This is the div that I have to wait for because contains the main data of the product
product_info = soup.find('div', class_='product-info')
```

Is there any possibility of skipping that step and instead of that query directly to their database simulating that the request is from the website and extracting the .json with the data?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: So if you're going directly to the database, that's either an api or your hacking. For an api, you wouldnt use beautifulSoup and selenium, you would just make REST requests. If you're trying to scrape a website without running Javascript then something like `options.preferences.update({"javascript.enabled": False})` might work, but if it's a website built using React, Angular or Vue, then you want that javascript, because the website is empty without it

Comment: The website needs javascript to fully loaded, I will try with REST requests, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the page directly with `requests` and parse it. Without using `selenium` and waiting for the JavaScript:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.jumbo.cl/yoghurt-loncoleche-proteina-natural-c-endulzante-140-g/p"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

product_info = soup.select_one(".product-info")

title = product_info.h1.get_text(strip=True)
price = product_info.select_one(".product-single-price-container").find_next(
    text=True
)

print("Title:", title)
print("Price:", price)
```

Prints:

```
Title: Yoghurt proteína natural endulzado 140 g
Price: $ 445
```